# How to send email with phpMailer and fetch API

Tags: fetch-api, phpmailer

I'm trying to create a sending email button on my website.
You can see it there :[text](https://julietcolombe.fr)
I'm using the fetch API that captures information on click, and sends it to my phpEmail.php file which is supposed to send me an email.

To test on my local I use mailtrap.io and the reception is ok, and I get the response of my fetch in my log.
But when I'm trying in prod, even if I have the good params and credentials Ionos (I've alradeay check with them), the reception doesn't work anymore and the fetch response is "empty string".

This is my js code :

```
async function sendEmail() {

    var url = 'https://julietcolombe.fr/wp-content/themes/julietcolombe/sendEmail.php';
    var drawingData = canvas.toDataURL();
    var image = encodeURIComponent(drawingData);

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('drawingData', image);

    fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: formData })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (body) {
            console.log(body);
        });

}

var sendEmailButton = document.getElementById('envoyerBtn');
sendEmailButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    sendEmail();
});
```

And this is my sendEmail.php for prod:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require \vendor\autoload.php';

    try {

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Host = "smtp.ionos.com";
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->Username = "****";
        $mail->Password = "****";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    
        $mail->From = "****@julietcolombe.fr";
        $mail->addAddress("****@julietcolombe.fr");
    
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
        $mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
        $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";
    
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
    
        $mail->send();
    
        echo "OK";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Mailer Eror : {$e->getMessage()}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the fetch example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform-ajax.phps)? Also, check your email sending separately from your JS, as you're currently trying to diagnose through several layers at once.